# 0x800703EE When trying to install Windows Update 1903

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I recently reinstalled Windows on my SSD and it is now refusing to update to 1903 with an error of 0x800703EE without further description. **This error was asked several times on SU, but with no good answers, because none of the answers in [Getting error 0x800703ee when trying to upgrade Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1457087/getting-error-0x800703ee-when-trying-to-upgrade-windows-10) works for me.** Notice the OP of that post never did accept an answer.

Here are a few points regarding my situation:

- My Windows is version 1809
- I have a dual boot Ubuntu on my system.
- I have messed with the booting partition. I have used AOMEI to shrink my Windows primary partition. Fast boot is off. I accidentally deleted the boot partition, and reconstructed it according to: http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/?fbclid=IwAR1MFp_OuUlVYvESLu9-_hNdDqzubRsYd-dfNMpynjYTShyYDBJJGj0I0a0
- Other cumulative Windows Updates were successful.
- I have run `sfc /scannow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. It did fix a problem, but they both says my PC is fine now.
- Online searching has lead me to believe the error code might be the one related to: "The volume for a file has been externally altered such that the opened file is no longer valid." However, I do not see this message explicitly in any log

Can anyone help with this error? I'd love to provide more information.

[image]

[image]

The associated XML description:

```xml
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient
Date:          10/25/2019 12:35:40 AM
Event ID:      20
Task Category: Windows Update Agent
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Failure,Installation
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      COMPUTER NAME
Description:
Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800703EE: Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient" Guid="{945a8954-c147-4acd-923f-40c45405a658}" />
    <EventID>20</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>1</Task>
    <Opcode>13</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000028</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-24T16:35:40.975484800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>49631</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="5052" ThreadID="1468" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>COMPUTER NAME</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="errorCode">0x800703ee</Data>
    <Data Name="updateTitle">Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903</Data>
    <Data Name="updateGuid">{c6a0bbfe-fa2b-4d86-aab4-fb51f87b459e}</Data>
    <Data Name="updateRevisionNumber">1</Data>
    <Data Name="serviceGuid">{8b24b027-1dee-babb-9a95-3517dfb9c552}</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**WindowsUpdate.log excerpt**

```
2019/10/25 00:48:44.3218564 5052  1468  DownloadManager *FAILED* [8024000C] DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete
2019/10/25 00:48:56.1837108 5052  11392 DownloadManager ExtractUpdateFiles
2019/10/25 00:48:56.2338791 5052  11392 DataStore       Service 8F9D09EA-B8FB-4BD8-A7B9-281E08077B5A removed
2019/10/25 00:48:56.2338909 5052  11392 Agent           RemoveTargetedServiceMapping: 8F9D09EA-B8FB-4BD8-A7B9-281E08077B5A -> 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D
2019/10/25 00:50:07.5218089 9716  7000  Handler         Install complete for update ID: C6A0BBFE-FA2B-4D86-AAB4-FB51F87B459E.1 Return code is 0x800703EE. Requires Reboot:No
2019/10/25 00:50:07.5218108 9716  7000  Handler         Enter deployment handler NotifyResult
2019/10/25 00:50:07.5219540 9716  7000  Handler         Leave deployment handler NotifyResult
2019/10/25 00:50:07.5219570 9716  7000  Handler         *FAILED* [800703EE] Leave deployment handler Install
2019/10/25 00:50:07.6358057 5052  14980 Agent           LogHistory called. idUpdate={C6A0BBFE-FA2B-4D86-AAB4-FB51F87B459E}.1, resultMapped=800703EE, resultUnMapped=0
2019/10/25 00:50:07.6365964 5052  14980 Agent           Install updates CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator
2019/10/25 00:50:07.6367390 9236  3124  ComApi           Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
```

[image]

Screenshot of AOMEI Partition Assistant:

[image]

GParted Screenshot:

`sdb3` contains the Windows Boot loader. `sda3` contains GRUB, I believe, whatever that boots up Ubuntu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error 0x800703ee when trying to upgrade Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1457087/getting-error-0x800703ee-when-trying-to-upgrade-windows-10)

Comment: Please post a shot of the drive in Disk Management.

Comment: @Moab Yes, I also think so. But that post is pretty much dead now.

Comment: @Moab posted drive shot.

Comment: Error 0x800703EE carries the text "The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have seen this on my search, but is there a place where I can find "which" file or volume was causing the trouble?

Comment: @Moab The link you suggested for for the error associated with  0x8007000E, Not enough storage is available to complete this operation." Not the same error.

Comment: @DanielCheung - Yet; **Your system also does not have a system reserved partition.**  So the answer to the duplicate is applicable to your issue.  The error codes are exactly the same.

Comment: Update your question to indicate what version of Windows 10 you are currently installed.

Comment: @Ramhound That is curious, that Disk Management didn't show the MRP. I have tried to create an MRP according to the article http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/?fbclid=IwAR1MFp_OuUlVYvESLu9-_hNdDqzubRsYd-dfNMpynjYTShyYDBJJGj0I0a0 when I accidentally removed my EFI Boot Partition.

Comment: @DanielCheung - I see you have multiple EFI partitions across multiple disks, which could be a problem if the active EFI partition is on a different disk.  When the upgrade failed, a log was created, provide the relevant information from that log. The name of this log is well documented.  If your MRP is on another partition other than the system partition, the inability to upgrade your windows installation is explained by that fact.

Comment: @Ramhound I just checked online, the System Reserved Partition is essentially the boot files. But I already have my 100MB FAT32 Windows Boot partition on my second disk. I can boot to Windows without any problem. Is that not the same thing? Furthermore, is the suspicion of the system missing the SRP causing the problem logged anywhere?

Comment: @Ramhound And by "the log is well documented". So you mean WindowsUpdate.log? I generated one and it didn't explain anything. The except I've included contains the relevant text already, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

One remark I can make is that your EFI partition is too small for Windows 10.
It should be at least 500 MB. I suggest to resize some partition on the
boot disk so as to leave at least 1 GB of unallocated space, then try again.

If this doesn't help, then something is messed up in Windows and it would
be pretty hard to analyze what went wrong.
You have already tried all the standard advice given for such
problems, without solution. It is possible that this was caused by the Linux
installation, if it ever modified anything on the Windows partition.

I would suggest to use the
[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
to do an offline upgrade of Windows in order to set all components to a
known state.
This might short-circuit the dual-boot with Linux, so you may need to fix
that afterward.

For more information, see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

In case that the problem still arrives, try doing this while booting in
Safe mode.

Comment: I checked with GParted and my Windows EFI is still having around 80MB free disk space though.

Comment: In my experience, if installing a feature upgrade fails through Windows Update, it will also fail with the upgrade Assistant and the Media Creation Tool.  The process to download and install the feature update is identical using all three methods.

Comment: The 80MB free disk space relates to the currently installed version. Windows 10 itself now allocates 500 MB whenever it has the space for it.

Comment: @harrymc - You sure about that?  I have a fresh installation of WIndows 10 version 1903 and my EFI partition is only 100 MB.  Infact looking all my systems I don't have a single system with a 500 MB EFI partition.

Comment: @Ramhound: I only have 500 MB partitions, and this same advice worked for other posts here, so I would still advise it (even if it is not the problem here).

Comment: The Boot drive has 513mb? The other drive looks like storage.